# Разница между значением частоты ЦПУ из полного названия процессора и поля CPU MHz (получаемых посредством lscpu)

Tags: процессор

`lscpu` показывает частоту процессора (поле `CPU MHz`), равную 2700 МГц, а название (`Intel(R) Xeon(R) D-2141I CPU @ 2.20GHz`) содержит в себе меньший показатель частоты.

В чем разница, и на какое показание ориентироваться? Показание необходимо для составления документации о сервере, используемой администраторами поддержки.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим характеристики процессора по его названию, например, на [cpubenchmark.net](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Xeon%20D-2141I%20%40%202.20GHz&id=3379):

```
Clockspeed: 2.2 GHz
Turbo Speed: 3.0 GHz
```

В режиме "турбо" частота этого процессора может подниматься до 3Ггц. Но формально у него таки 2.2Гц рабочая частота. Смотрите всё-таки характеристики по названию модели.

В процессе работы частота процессора может быть и выше формальной и ниже формальной (но в определённых рамках), для современных процессоров это нормально.